# How to replace "in which" in a question

Tags: meaning-in-context, questions

Do the following questions convey the same meaning? If not, how can I change 1) to a standard form 2)?

```
1) Hemolytic disease of the newborn is a risk during a subsequent pregnancy in which ________.

2) Which of the following in hemolytic disease of the newborn is a risk during a subsequent pregnancy?
```

Comment: They both sound better as written than any alternative I can come up with, however ,you could use "where" in the first case instead of "in which," but the second one really needs "which" since you are asking them to select an item. You could say "select the risk below that....." but the way it is written now is better so I would not change it.

Comment: The first statement is not a question, and the second one is.  Because of this difference, they can never convey the same meaning.  If you want a precise answer, you need to change the form of the first statement into a question.